# error met when rosmake openni_kinect

Tags: rosmake, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello,
I met a big problem when I want to rosmake the openni_kinect package.
The following is the printed-out msg during the rosmake procedure.
Could anyone help me out of this problem? Really appreciate!**

walon@walon-ROS:~/ros/drivers$ rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['openni_kinect']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/walon/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110520-172547
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['openni_kinect'] to:
['openni_camera_unstable', 'openni_camera', 'openni_tracker', 'nite', 'openni']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#Packages
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 openni-dev python-sip4-dev ps-engine libqhull-dev nite-dev libcppunit-dev libhdf5-serial-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
}}}
[sudo] password for walon:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nite-dev: Depends: openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid) but 1.1.0.41-3+lucid1 is to be installed
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: rosdep script failed with stderr
{{{
E: Broken packages

}}}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10012/error-met-when-rosmake-openni_kinect/) by [walonchiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/569/walonchiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [walonchiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/569/walonchiu/) on 2011-05-23**:
Actually the version of openni-dev now is 1.1.0.41-3+lucid1. But for installing nite-dev, it request for the openni-dev (= 0.1.0~lucid).  So I guess I should find out the older version of openni-dev... But I cant find out one.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-22**:
Hm, package conflicts. "sudo apt-get update" could help you, but I guess not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the state of packages I use (on ubuntu 10.10). Maybe you can force the versions manually (e.g. `apt-get install packagename=packageversion`)

```
Package: libcppunit-dev            Version: 1.12.1-1build1
Package: python-sip4-dev           Version: 4.10.5-0ubuntu1
Package: libgraphicsmagick++1-dev  Version: 1.3.12-1
Package: libhdf5-serial-dev        Version: 1.8.4-patch1-2ubuntu1
Package: libqhull-dev              Version: 2009.1-1
Package: python-wxgtk2.8           Version: 2.8.11.0-0ubuntu4
Package: nite-dev                  Version: 0.0.2~maverick
Package: openni-dev                Version: 0.0.2~maverick
Package: ps-engine                 Version: 0.0.2~maverick
Package: python-wxgtk2.8           Version: 2.8.11.0-0ubuntu4.1
```

The backup solution would be to compile openni_kinect from source yourself. If you want to try that, checkout the mercurial repository somewhere into a directory you add(ed) to the front of your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:

```
hg checkout https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros
rosmake openni_ros
```

There will be no version conflicts then, but you'd still need to install all requirements.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [walonchiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/569/walonchiu/) on 2011-05-23**:
Thank you! Felix! It does solve the problem!